# Telerik MVC Grid Foreign Key Column Dynamic Dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, foreign-keys, telerik-grid

I have the following in my Telerik grid:

```
columns.ForeignKey(x => x.TutorUsername, (Tutor.GetAllTutors()), "username", "fullName").Title("Tutor").Width(150);
```

This works great it gives me a dropdown of all the tutors with it's value tied to the TutorUsername for each row.

I want to take this one step further and make the dropdown list dynamic for each row., something like this:

```
columns.ForeignKey(x => x.TutorUsername, (Tutor.GetSubjectTutors(x => x.subjectCode)), "username", "fullName").Title("Tutor").Width(150);
```

The subjectCode is returned for each row I just can't figure out how to access it inside the GetSubjectTutors() method as described above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!